# Spring When routing inputChannel first channel is always wrong

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using

- spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.3.RELEASE
- spring-integration-ip-4.3.17.RELEASE
- spring-integration-http-4.3.17.RELEASE

Given this code to generate dynamically TCP connections. I define the ReveiverAdapter and SenderAdapter.

```
IntegrationFlow ifr = existsConnection(connectionId);
    if (ifr == null) {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        final ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer by = new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(headBytes);
        cf.setSingleUse(false);
        cf.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        cf.setSerializer(by);
        cf.setDeserializer(by);
        cf.setComponentName(connectionId);

        //Inbound Adapter 
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        adapter.setClientMode(true);
        adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
        adapter.setRetryInterval(retryInterval);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(bme.fromTcp());
        //OutBound Adapter
        TcpSendingMessageHandler sender = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        sender.setConnectionFactory(cf);

        ifr = IntegrationFlows.from(adapter)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("connectionId",connectionId))
                .handle(sender).get();

        this.flowContext.registration(ifr).id(connectionId+CONNECTION_SUFFIX).addBean(cf).register();
```

When I try to reroute to the correct channel the first time I run it I get "fromTcp" instead of the sender adapter, when I recover the channel from IntegrationFlow.getInputChannel()

Answer (score 1):

I think you have somewhere one more subscriber for that `bme.fromTcp()`, so in the flow you get one more with the `.enrichHeaders()` and I guess that `fromTcp` is a `DirectChannel` which is based on the `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy` by default, so incoming messages are balanced between your subscribers.

Not sure what is your intention, but consider do not inject that  `bme.fromTcp()` into the `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` and Java DSL will take care about implicit channel injection in betweed `from(adapter)` and `.enrichHeaders()`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that with .enrichHeaders() I get more suscribers. What I want to do with .enrichHeaders()  is to add a header called "connectionId" when I send a message through of the directChannel (fromTcp).  Could you give me any advice how to do that or do it differently?